# Caching with mod_rewrite

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like to re-write a request like http://www.example.com/videos such that Apache will fetch it from a cache directory in the document root
I need two conditions for this to happen:

1. the file does not have an extension, so no videos.css etc
2. the file exists in cache/

If the above conditions are not met, I would like to route the request to index.php.

What should I put in my .htaccess to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps something like this will work for you, if you create the cached files with a `.html` extension.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} GET
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cache/%{REQUEST_URI}\.html -f
RewriteRule .* cache/%{REQUEST_URI}\.html [L]
```

Comment: `the file does not have an extension`

Comment: When doing a full page cache I think it's wise to append the `.html` extension to the cached files.

Comment: It's an HTML page you're saving right? Then why not making it clear and allow the web server to recognise it as such.

Comment: The final implementation, based heavily on Kyra's answer is this:


   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

      RewriteEngine On

      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} GET
      RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
      RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cache/%{REQUEST_URI} -f
      RewriteRule .* cache/%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
      RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/?$ /index.php [L]
  
    </IfModule>

Answer (score 1):

Try these 2 rules:

```
RewriteEngine On

#forward to cache/<file> if it exists in %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cache
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cache/$1 -f
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ /cache/$1 [L]

# otherwise forward to /index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cache/$1 !-f
RewriteRule ^ /index.php [L]
```

Comment: This did not work. When I try http://www.example.com/video it roots to index.php even though cache/video exists.

Comment: Please check the latest edited answer.